# Evaluating a matrix by row for a condition being met in R

Tags: r, matrix

I've got data in the following format.

```
    P10_neg._qn P11_neg._qn P12_neg._qn P14_neg._qn P17_neg._qn P24_neg._qn P25_neg._qn
1      -0.025      -0.037      -0.032      -0.061      -0.176       0.033      -0.011
2      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087
3       0.033      -0.127       0.042       0.014       0.097       0.105       0.048
4       0.033      -0.127       0.042       0.014       0.097       0.105       0.048
5      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087
6      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087
```

What is the best way by which I can check, for every row, how many entries are greater than 0.1, for instance and return a vector of counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rowSum` function for this task. Assuming that `dat` is you matrix then :

```
rowSum(dat > 0.1)
```

Using the sample data provided we have :

```
dat <- read.table(text = '   P10_neg._qn P11_neg._qn P12_neg._qn P14_neg._qn P17_neg._qn P24_neg._qn P25_neg._qn
1      -0.025      -0.037      -0.032      -0.061      -0.176       0.033      -0.011
2      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087
3       0.033      -0.127       0.042       0.014       0.097       0.105       0.048
4       0.033      -0.127       0.042       0.014       0.097       0.105       0.048
5      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087
6      -0.029      -0.125       0.003      -0.098       0.117       0.039       0.087',
                  row.names = 1, header = TRUE)

rowSums(dat > 0.1)
## 1 2 3 4 5 6 
## 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) sum(x>.1))
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here an Rcpp version:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector countGreaterThan2(NumericMatrix M,double val) {
  IntegerVector res;
  for (int i=0; i<M.nrow(); i++) {
    NumericVector row = M( i, _);
    double num = std::count_if(row.begin(), row.end(),    
                       [&val](const double& x) -> bool {return x>val;});  
    res.push_back(num);
  }
  return res;
}
```

But `rowSum` is unbeatable:

```
system.time(rowSums(dfx>0.2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> system.time(countGreaterThan2(dfx,0.2))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.00    0.06
```